# How can I get the tid (term id) using the id of my node in .theme

Tags: 8, nodes, taxonomy-terms

I need to get the id of the node category.

I try this:

```
$variables['tid'] = $node->field_category->target_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I wrote this answer thinking the question was for Drupal 7. This is not accurate for Drupal 8.*

If you debug the $node object, you will see that it's more complicated than that. It has a language and probably a value index. So, you could access the TID this way:

```
$variables['tid'] = $node->field_category[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id'];
```

But, don't do it that way. It would be better to use EntityMetadataWrapper. The code should look something like this:

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$variables['tid'] = $wrapper->field_category->raw();
```

If you want the whole term object, you can do this:

```
$variables['term'] = $wrapper->field_category->value();
```

Comment: entity_metadata_wrapper is a Drupal 7 thing, it can't be used in Drupal 8 (mainly because it's obsolete)

Comment: I didn't notice that the question was for Drupal 8. I will clarify my response.